# Cannot Add Internet Accounts

Tags: macos, internet, accounts

I'm running OSX 10.12.6.  For some random reason, my internet accounts pane has cleared & I cannot add any new accounts:

[image: Internet Accounts]

I'm an IT tech & can confirm that I have not manually removed the account. 
 I did have an update the other day, but not sure what it was as I didn't investigate.

iCloud is still registered.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you pressed a provider name first, in the right pane, e.g google if you have a google account?

Comment: @Yoan excuse the slow response. They aren't selectable.  Something to do with the ui is corrupted.  I can hover (& get the corresponding white highlight), but cannot select a service at all.

Answer (score 1):

This answer resolved the issue for me: [Can't login with Google using Internet Accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223441/279727)