# macOS prompts to log in to Google accounts on every wake

Tags: macos, mojave, sleep-wake, google, authentication

I have several Google accounts set up in System Preferences > Internet Accounts on macOS 10.14.5. The Google accounts have two-factor authentication. I'm able to log in the accounts via a Safari window, and then use them with Mail and Calendar without problems.

Until my Mac sleeps.  On wake, it demands that I log the accounts in again, requiring several rounds of password and two-factor authentication.

I have tried using Google's app-specific passwords, but they aren't accepted at the login prompt that pops up from System Preferences > Internet Accounts.

Is there a method to keep macOS logged in indefinitely?

Note: This does not appear to have the same cause as [Can't login with Google using Internet Accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221839/cant-login-with-google-using-internet-accounts) — the answers there did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't login with Google using Internet Accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221839/cant-login-with-google-using-internet-accounts)

Comment: That problem doesn't have the same symptoms but I'll try the various solutions mentioned there and make an edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those solutions affect this problem in my case, so this isn't obviously a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, it would be good to [edit] your question to indicate you tried the solutions in that question and they didn't work.  That way everyone will know it's not a dup (comments can be deleted).

Comment: [Mail app loses username-password for google apps account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362596/macos-mail-app-loses-usernames-password-for-google-apps-accounts?noredirect=1&lq=1) has/had an bounty with no answers yet. @fsb ping.

Comment: Do you have little snitch or some other firewall installed ?

Comment: I did have Little Snitch installed, and I have the macOS firewall enabled.  However removing Little Snitch has not helped.  I'll do some more digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting my Google accounts in System Prefrences and replacing them with generic IMAP mail and CalDAV calendar accounts using Google's generated [app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).  These do not expire except when I ask them to on Google's site.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you have that problem, you might want to check that googleapis.com and other google domains aren't blocked by a firewall (if you are using little snitch, double check that `accountsd` can access google apis.

Once I allowed `accountsd` outgoing internet access to googleapis.com, as shown in the attached screenshot, the mac no longer complained when woken up from sleep that I needed to enter my password for my GSuite account.[image: like that screenshot]

If that doesn't work, you can maybe look for a DNS server or a host file that would block the googleapis aswell.

Comment: Thanks.  This did look likely, but I only have the system firewall enabled and could not find any rule blocking accountsd.  Since I solved the problem another way https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376882/158980 I haven't experimented with disabling the firewall altogether.